# How to display all pages and all chapters using nl.siegmann.epublib

Tags: android, epub

This is what I tried to perform the task if anyone can help out it would be most appreciated. So in this code it will display just the cover page. I read http://www.siegmann.nl/static/epublib/apidocs/ that you could use `getSpine()` to get everything but it only displayed one thing on my case which is cover page.

```
webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
AssetManager am = getAssets();
try {
    InputStream epubInputStream = am.open(bookName);
    book = (new EpubReader()).readEpub(epubInputStream);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("epublib", e.getMessage());
}

Spine spine = book.getSpine(); 
for (SpineReference bookSection : spine.getSpineReferences()) {
    Resource res = bookSection.getResource();

    try {
        InputStream is = res.getInputStream();
        StringBuffer string = new StringBuffer();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                linez =   string.append(line + "\n").toString();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        //do something with stream
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
webView.loadData(linez, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Comment: I fixed the problem ill put up my answer when I get back home since I have less that 100 rep points.

Comment: Hello, Can you post the Answer? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what I figured out using spine on http://www.siegmann.nl/static/epublib/apidocs/ is that it still works by sections. So I tried to figure out how many sections are there by identifying count numbers. Then placed those numbers in `Resource res = spine.getResource(i);`. If you would do `Resource res = spine.getResource(2);` It would display the spine of 2 which should be chapter 2 unless someone messes up the format of the epub.

```
Spine spine = book.getSpine(); 
List<SpineReference> spineList = spine.getSpineReferences() ;
int count = spineList.size();
tv.setText(Integer.toString(count));
StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; count > i; i++) {
    Resource res = spine.getResource(i);

    try {
        InputStream is = res.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                linez =   string.append(line + "\n").toString();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        //do something with stream
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
webView.loadData(linez, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Comment: `Resource res` , `InputStream is` , `BufferedReader reader` should be declared outside the loop... Also, avoid using numerous try-catch unless really needed....

Comment: how we can identified pages in a string ?